# How can I secure an outwardly opening front door without damaging anything?

Tags: doors, tools, lock, security

This is a rented house in Japan (single room).

It has an outwardly opening front door. The resident (a single woman) has fear of intruder breaking in. Also, damaging/modifying the door or the wall is not welcomed and makes thing complicated.

How can she reinforce her front door in this situation?

I recently heard her story and found this video [SWATLOC-Introduction](http://youtu.be/SC-Z6JmDrmI), it looks good, but I can't find actual buying information for the product.

Comment: a piece of wood and some rope will do the same thing

Comment: You could try calling them, http://www.buzzfile.com/business/Swatloc,-LLC-215-536-8656

Comment: what are the concerns? Not being able to tell who is at the door without opening it? Is it the hinge pins being removed to gain access? Or is it just the general integrity of the lock?

Answer (score 2):

For outward opening doors that need security against having the hinge pin removed, you can get hinges with a security stud in the hinge.

[image]

<sub>Sample image from Home Depot, no product or vendor affiliation</sub>

The small stud protruding between the middle screw holes prevents the door from being removed from the hinge while the door is closed.

You can create a similar result with a DIY solution by placing a long screw or lag bolt in the door frame that is left protruding almost 1/2" near each hinge. And on the door, drill a small hole to receive the screw head. It wouldn't hurt to cover that hole with a deadbolt strike plate to make it more difficult to force the door off and give it a more finished look.

These options are both on the hinge side of the door and have no need to install/remove as you use them. Most property owners wouldn't have a problem having something like this installed since you're securing their home.

Comment: Removing the pins and shifting the door toward the latch would allow bypass of this mechanism. Hinges with tamper-proof pins would be a much more secure option.

Comment: There are hinges with locks that protrude further out. But if you have a lot of play between your doorband door frame, that's also a problem.

Answer (score 1):

The original person has probably moved from japan but it's still a valid question.  Either buy or make a screw or stud yourself, don't rely on that little punch out thing on the so-called stud hinges.  To make a screw, take out one screw, put one in twice as long leaving half sticking out, cut off the head, then either remove the facing screw or if not aligned drill a hole so when the door closes the sticking out part goes into the hole. Or you can buy headless screws made for that purpose, just search for "security stud for hinge".
Do that for each hinge and the door can't be lifted or shifted over.  Just make sure your lock and jamb are sturdy or it's all for naught since a well placed boot could splinter a cheap door.  Granted, it's much easier to splinter an inward opening door.  Pay no attention to the full-light glass, *surely* nobody would break that...

Answer (score 1):

I have an outswinging entryway door where I live in a studio cottage. As long as the door does not have glass on the lower 2/3rds of the door, they are really very secure doors. No one can kick them in when closed. The first thing you need to do is make sure you have security hinges so no one can just come along and take out the hinge pin and remove the door.  There's a few different types- 
1) "Setscrew" hinges: you can buy or diy.  These have a screw that goes through the pin so it can not be removed
[image: Setscrew hinge]

2) Stud Hinges that have a metal rod on each side of the hinge plate that sticks out and goes into a hole on the opposite plate.  The pin can be removed but then there is no way to remove the door from the frame when in the closed position.
[image: stud hinges]

3)Security hinges work the same way that stud hinges work but instead of a rod, there is a metal tab that sticks out so again pin can be removed but then there is no way to remove the door from the frame when in the closed position.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a CinchLock temporary door lock for outward opening doors.  http://www.cinchlock.com.  They are designed for use on outward opening doors and are manufactured in California.  Easy to install and remove.  Standard width is 44" long.

Comment: If you are affiliated **in any way** with the product that you linked to, you **must** disclose that. Please see the [expected behavior](http://diy.stackexchange.com/help/behavior), [product support](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/product-support) and [promotion](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/promotion) pages in the [help] for more information.

Comment: Looks like a reasonably secure (if slightly cumbersome) solution. Why the suspicion about product affiliation?